# [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript

estoy empezando con la programacion  y mas concreto con javascript
me ha surgido un problema con un ejercicio que no se como resolver ,cuando intento menter el texto del input en mi lista con la tecla enter  , en vez del texto . se me agrega a la lista lo siguiente :[object HTMLInputElement]
os dejo en enlace el codigo completo por si quereis una vision mas general , gracias
https://github.com/Wolfdog940/Pruebas-ejercicio-1-y-2.git

````
```
`var input2 = document.getElementById('mi input');

input2.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
var input2= document.getElementById('mi input');
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.textContent= input2;
if(event.key == "Enter") {
    
tareas.appendChild(li);



}`




});`

```
````

Comment: Podés crear un [repro] en tu pregunta insertando un _snippet_ (con el botón que indica `<>`). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por cierto: 1. Estás seteando a _li_ no el valor de _input2_, sino _input2_ como tal. 2. Los id [no deben llevar espacios en blanco](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). ¡No olvides leer la documentación! Tampoco olvides _buscar e investigar_ antes de realizar una pregunta. Preguntar debe ser tu último recurso.

Comment: Gracias , solucionado

Comment: No olvides colocarlo como respuesta y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.